# Center only the prompt text of textfield

Tags: java, javafx, alignment, textfield

Is there a way to center the prompt text of a JavaFX TextField possibly using CSS? I've just been adhoc-ing it by putting spaces in front of the prompt text, but sometimes it's still slightly off.

[[N    ] http://i65.tinypic.com/i2kobl.png](http://i65.tinypic.com/i2kobl.png) -> [[  N  ] http://i66.tinypic.com/2mxr0jk.png](http://i66.tinypic.com/2mxr0jk.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Prompt text is shown in the text field when it is empty and doesn't have the focus. There is a CSS pseudoclass for `focused` but there is no predefined CSS pseudoclass for "empty", so you need to create one:

```
TextField textField = new TextField();
textField.setPromptText("Enter something");

PseudoClass empty = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("empty");

textField.pseudoClassStateChanged(empty, textField.getText().isEmpty());

textField.textProperty().isEmpty().addListener((obs, wasEmpty, isNowEmpty) -> 
        textField.pseudoClassStateChanged(empty, isNowEmpty));
```

And now you can use CSS as follows to set the alignment to center when the text field is empty, and to the default center-left when the text field is empty and focused.

SSCCE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.css.PseudoClass;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CenterPromptText extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextField textField = new TextField();
        textField.setPromptText("Enter something");

        PseudoClass empty = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("empty");

        textField.pseudoClassStateChanged(empty, textField.getText().isEmpty());

        textField.textProperty().isEmpty().addListener((obs, wasEmpty, isNowEmpty) -> 
                textField.pseudoClassStateChanged(empty, isNowEmpty));

        VBox root = new VBox(5, textField, new Button("OK"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("center-prompt-text.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

with `center-prompt-text.css`:

```css
.text-field:empty {
    -fx-alignment: center ;
}
.text-field:empty:focused {
    -fx-alignment: center-left ;
}

/*
 * settings on root just for cosmetic appearance;
 * 
 */

.root {
    -fx-padding: 20 ;
    -fx-alignment: center ;
}
```

When you focus on the button, the prompt text appears and is centered:

[image]

If you focus the text field, it reverts to left-aligned (so the cursor shows in the left):

[image]

and if you enter text, the `empty` pseudoclass is unset, so text is left-aligned whether or not it is focused:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the very complete answer.